# Wall furnace material - could it be asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

Found it on a shelf in my wall furnace, hence the burnt look... looking for input on its origin.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**It could be.**

A few things you've left out where the year of the build of your home and the area you are in. These could help narrow down if this was used in your area at the time of construction.

You have two options:

1. Pickup a test kit from your local hardware store - or bring a sample to be tested by a lab.
2. Call a qualified professional for an opinion: Knowledgeable contractors can identify this immediately or you can contact the local authority in your area who deals with asbestos.

Asbestos used in insulation wraps are typically OK unless they are disturbed. Since there is a doubt, stop everything you are doing until you've confirmed what it is.

Comment: Sadly the fabric was already disturbed. The case was removed from the furnace and it was being cleaned when that was discovered. Initially, we thought it was build up of dust due to its outer color.